# Several STOMP consumers from queue processing each message once

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp

I have a queue on RabbitMQ and an app consuming from that queue via STOMP. I would like to have 2 or more instances of my app consuming from the same queue.

How can I consume each message in the queue once and only once? For instance, if I have messages A, B, C in the queue I want my apps to consume the messages likes this:

- Instance 1: A
- Instance 2: B,C

And NOT like this:

- Instance 1: A, B, C
- Instance 2: A, B, C

Comment: How is the queue configured on RabbitMQ? It sounds like it's configured to act like a topic (i.e. pub/sub semantics) rather than a queue.

Comment: So all I need to do is to create a STOMP queue in rabbit? How can I specify that certain queue will be accessed using STOMP protocol? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't configure a "STOMP queue" RabbitMQ, per se. The [STOMP specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Protocol_Overview) does not define what the delivery semantics of destinations should be. As noted in the [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html#d) you can use a handful of different prefixes to get the semantics you want. What prefix are you using when you send and consume messages?

Comment: The documentation about prefixes was clear for me. Thanks! PD: If you want you can create an answer with the info in the comments so I can select it as correct.

Comment: I added an answer with the relevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't configure a "STOMP queue" in RabbitMQ, per se. The [STOMP specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Protocol_Overview) does not define what the delivery semantics of destinations should be. As noted in the [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html#d) you can use a handful of different prefixes to get the semantics you want, e.g.:

> - `/exchange` -- `SEND` to arbitrary routing keys and `SUBSCRIBE` to arbitrary binding patterns;
> - `/queue` -- `SEND` and `SUBSCRIBE` to queues managed by the STOMP gateway;
> - `/amq/queue` -- `SEND` and `SUBSCRIBE` to queues created outside the STOMP gateway;
> - `/topic` -- `SEND` and `SUBSCRIBE` to transient and durable topics;
> - `/temp-queue/` -- create temporary queues (in `reply-to` headers only).